# Unable to uncheck Version Info in Delphi 2007 Project

Tags: delphi, version, delphi-2007

The following link pretty much describes the problem I have.

[In a Dunit project and exe version info is disabled, how do I get it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891396/in-a-dunit-project-and-exe-version-info-is-disabled-how-do-i-get-it-back)

The difference is that in my case I'm using Delphi 2007, I have the "Include version information in project" checked and can't uncheck it, and I do have the `{$R *.res}` in my project file. I'm not sure what else could be the problem.

Here's the list of files I got for the package:

```
01/02/2014  05:41 PM             7,338 CnvBpl.dpk
01/03/2014  12:26 PM            60,643 CnvBpl.dproj
01/02/2014  05:53 PM                62 CnvBpl.dproj.local
01/02/2014  06:55 PM           368,559 CnvBpl.drc
01/02/2014  05:55 PM            10,938 CnvBpl.dsk
01/02/2014  05:28 PM             3,180 CnvBpl.res
12/26/2013  11:16 AM               710 CnvBpl.txt
01/02/2014  05:41 PM            10,937 CnvBpl.~dsk
```

Here's the content of the package:

```
package CnvBpl;

{$R *.res}
{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS ON}
.....
```

There's no other reference to a .res file in the .dpr.

I also deleted the .res file and let delphi recreate it but I still get the checkbox disabled.

**Edited 1/6/2014**

I manually modified the .dproj file to have this:

```
...Package_Options><VersionInfo><VersionInfo Name="IncludeVerInfo">False</VersionInfo><VersionInfo Name="AutoIncBuild">False</VersionInfo>...
```

When I open the package again with Delphi IDE it still shows the check box grayed out and enabled. If I make another change to the project and save it, it saves the setting back as True in the .dproj file.

Comment: What's in the .res file? What is its name? What is the name of your .dpr file?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to disable version info, you can do that by editing the dproj file. But I have no idea, why the ide won't let you do that. Usually it's because the {*.res} entry is missing, but that apparently isn't the case.